# Drag and drop JLabel to windows taskbar

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlabel

I have made a launcher for my games, and I was wondering if there is a way to drag the games icon (JLabel) to the windows taskbar and give it the target of "launcher.exe {Game_Name}", which will launch the game automatically without showing the launcher GUI.

Comment: Why does the game have a `launcher.exe`?  How is it launched on *nix & OS X?  Note: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: I will change to JWS, but you didn't really answer my initial question, also the launcher isn't for the game itself, it's  where you have a list of my games, and it launches them, just like Steam

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but JWS has facilities to install desktop shortcuts and menu items for an app.